# Find the maximum rate of change of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

So i have this function:

$$f(x,y,z) = 4x^3yz^2+2xz^3+xyz$$

And the question is: What is the direction u for this directional derivative $f'(u,(1,-1,-1))$ to be maximal and what is the direction u for this directional derivative?

I know that $\bigtriangledown f|(1,-1,-1)=(-13,3,13)$, should i just do $\sqrt{-13^2+3^2+13^2}$?

if not, what is the correct way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to solve this because I forgot what he directional derivative is.  Hopefully someone will see this and be able to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The gradient at a point will give you the direction of maximum *increase* in the value of the function. Its direction will be $\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$ In your case:

$$\nabla f = (12x^2yz^2+2z^3+yz,4x^3z^2+xz,8x^3yz+6xz^2+xy)$$

Therefore,

$$\nabla f(1,-1,-1) = (-13,3,13)$$

As you have already calculated.

It's direction would be 
$$\frac{(-13,3,13)}{\sqrt{2(13^2)+9}} \approx (-0.698,0.161,0.698)$$

Comment: That's an answer? How is it calculated?

Comment: @spexel how is what calculated?

Comment: (-13,3,13)/sqrt(2(13)^2+9)

Comment: @spexel that is just the gradient vector (which you calculated), divided by its magnitude. This will give you the direction.

Comment: @spexel note that you've correctly calculated the actual rate of change in that direction.

Comment: How do you divide (-13,3,13)?

Comment: @spexel - sorry, that was shorthand for scaling the gradient vector by its magnitude. I.e., component-wise division of the numerator by the value in the denominiator.

Comment: So what the final answer qould look like?

Comment: @spexel I updated my post